# Callback Javascript function after form validation in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, yii2

I am developing a new login module in Yii framework:

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    private $_user = false;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Form validation is working for above code and error message is visible in input box below. But I need to display global error message in top of the page.

I need callback function after form validation. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: you can simply print the errors in your view file using getErrors() method

Answer (score 2):

You can display the flash messages anywhere you want using the following snippet.

```
<?php
$flashMessages = Yii::app()->user->getFlashes();
if ($flashMessages) {
    echo '<ul class="flashes">';
    foreach($flashMessages as $key => $message) {
        echo '<li><div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div></li>\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

The way you utilize the flash messaging is totally depends on how your app and layout files are structured.

You can do the same using javascript

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
   'myHideEffect',
   '$(".info").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");',
   CClientScript::POS_READY
);
?>
```

More info on this can be found here [Yii Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)